# Description not visible in Facebook share using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the graph API to share a link to Facebook with a name (title), description and picture. My problem is that the description does not show up in my Facebook feed, only the picture and name are there, BUT I can see the description if I access the source of the page. It's inside a tag

```
<div class="_6m7 _3bt9"></div>
```

Is there something I can do to force Facebook to display this description ?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: Ok, and no way to know why sometimes Facebook displays this description, sometimes not? My link makes much less sense if the description is not with it.

Comment: It depends on a bunch of different factors. Have you used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see what Facebook sees of your URL

Comment: @WizKid I do not share a url that already exists, I create a share of a scheduled Wordpress post. So I input every field of the Facebook object like that:  
 $data['link'] = $url_post;
 $data['name'] = $title; 
 $data['type'] = 'link'; 
 $data['description'] = $description;

Comment: @WizKid I have a new information. I was able to see my description in a different browser. Any idea what could be blocking the description? I disabled my uBlock plugin (like Adblock) but it's not the culprit.